# Grails - schema configuration

Tags: grails, datasource

How can I configure Grails (in DataSource.groovy file) to use specific schema that a given username has access to, but it is not necessarily the default schema for that user.

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

I found a way to do it. 
Simply, add

hibernate.default_schema = 'schemaName'

In DataSource.groovy

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunetelly by DataSource.groovy you can't do that, because that information cannot be changed at runtime.